# Sorting Array of JSON Objects with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to sort an "entry" resource by months between different tables.

My data is as follows :

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        date: "2011-04-01",
        text: "My first entry"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        date: "2011-06-07",
        text: "My second entry"
    },
    ...
]
```

And I want to display the entries in different tables based on the month.

I've made a "months" array and tried this :

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months">
    <h3>{{month}}</h3>
    <ul ng-repeat="entry in entries">
        {{entry.text}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Of course, this puts every entry in every month. How can I only display the entries that belong in each month ?

Comment: That is **not** JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the "filter" filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months">
    <h3>{{month}}</h3>
    <ul ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter:{date:month}">
        {{entry.text}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

You'll need to do some manipulation of the date property to compare to the month.